# upgrade weblogic server 8.1 to 9.1

Tags: weblogic

I want to upgrade my weblogic server from 8.1 to 9.1.
what are the Risks involved to upgrade weblogic server 8.1 to 9.1? 
I need to know how can i upgrade my Weblogic application server from 8.1 to 9.1.
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps of upgrading weblogic server

1. Download Upgrade generic jar from oracle support site.
2. Copy that generic.jar to Local server Machine
3. Backup WEBLOGIC_HOME
4. Start the Upgrade(java -jar wls1036_upgrade_generic.jar)
5. Verify Upgrade

[image]

Detailed steps can be found here http://www.industryvertical.co.in/2013/05/how-to-upgrade-weblogic-server.html

Thanks